# Why use mqtt server for BLE gateway?

Tags: firebase, bluetooth-lowenergy, mqtt, iot, esp32

I have a BLE temperature sensor, which should send measurements to an ESP32 via a BLE connection and my plan was that the ESP32 could send the measurements via WiFi to my database (Firebase Realtime Database). However, I have seen from a few tutorials that a mqtt server would be neccesary (see the screenshot below - link to the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PBYCG-ypvRY). Could someone please explain to me why the mqtt component is neccesary? Currently I am measuring temperatures using my ESP32 (without the BLE temperautre sensors) and sending them directly to the database, so I am confused as to why with BLE I would need a mqtt server.

Thanks for your help in advance!

[image]

Comment: You don't send it "direct" to the database, You probably send it via http/https or some form of communication protocol to the server, and the server save it to the database. You don't need MQTT if you don't want, but you will need another form of communication protocol, such as HTTP.

Comment: @hcheung Thank you for your answer! When I am measuring temperatures using temperature sensor connected directly to ESP32 (without BLE) I am pushing them to Firebase using the Firebase-ESP32 library by mobitz. Do you think it's possible that the HTTP communication protocol to the server is already in the library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need MQTT. It's just one of the IoT-friendly protocol alternatives (like HTTPS, AMQP, CoAP, homebrew, etc) available to you for device-to-server communication. There are pros and cons to each one. It's up to you to choose whatever solution is relevant to your system.

If you've already implemented the Firebase HTTPS interface and it does the job, you're done.

If you are having problems, note that the [Google IoT Core](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/quickstart) also prescribes MQTT (or, alternatively HTTPS) as an underlying messaging protocol - used together with the [Device SDK for Embedded C](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/iot-device-sdk-embedded-c). But this is for people who want to have a large-scale authentication and management solution for their devices. By all means, stick to your existing solution if it works.